# Windows Logo Kit re-install/uninstall

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, driver-signing

I have to need to reinstall Windows Logo Kit but I have an issue as below;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs0jb.png

I tried to uninstall all Logo Kit stuff but I did not successful.

How can I uninstall/reinstall all Windows Logo Kit stuff ? Any idea or suggestion would be more than welcome.

Cheers

Comment: WLK-KitSetup.log -> http://pastebin.com/RVLR5ncA

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this issue with fresh OS installation and step by step installing WLK.

Cheers